# Summing rows in a DataTable, Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier

Tags: vb.net, datatable, sum, datarow, datacolumn

I have a datatable object which is populated from a database query.

I am trying to achieve a totals row using this function

```
Public Function getDataTable(data) As DataTable

    Dim theTable As New DataTable()
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Location"))
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Total Sales"))
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("VAT"))
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Refunds"))
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("VAT refund"))
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Total VAT"))
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Turnover"))
    theTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Turnover Net"))
    ' Location, Sale value, VAT, Refund, VAT refund, Total Vat, Turnover (Gross) 

    For Each ele In data
        Dim thisRow As DataRow = theTable.NewRow()
        thisRow.Item("location") = ele("name")
        thisRow.Item("Total Sales") = "£" & FormatNumber(ele("totalSales"), 2)
        thisRow.Item("VAT") = "£" & FormatNumber(ele("totalVat"), 2)
        thisRow.Item("Refunds") = "£" & FormatNumber(ele("refundTotal"), 2)
        thisRow.Item("VAT refund") = "£" & FormatNumber(ele("vatRefunded"), 2)
        thisRow.Item("Total VAT") = "£" & FormatNumber((ele("totalVat") - ele("vatRefunded")), 2)
        thisRow.Item("Turnover") = "£" & FormatNumber(ele("netSales"), 2)
        thisRow.Item("Turnover Net") = "£" & FormatNumber((ele("netSales") - ele("totalVat")), 2)
        theTable.Rows.Add(thisRow)
    Next

    Dim totalRow = theTable.NewRow
    For Each col As DataColumn In theTable.Columns
        If col.ColumnName <> "Location" Then
            Try
                totalRow(col.ColumnName) = Convert.ToDouble(theTable.Compute("SUM(CONVERT([" & col.ColumnName & "], CHAR(64)))", Nothing).ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                totalRow(col.ColumnName) = "grr"
            End Try
        Else
            totalRow("Location") = "Total"
        End If
    Next
    theTable.Rows.Add(totalRow)

    Return theTable
End Function
```

As you can see, we're creating a table with 8 columns, the first one being a location name, and the rest being numbers. I am skipping the summing of the "location" row with a simple `if` clause.

I keep getting this error though:

```
Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.
```

I've read a few posts, but nothing seems to solve it.

I thought the spaces in my column names might be an issue, this article suggested so:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1341960.aspx/1

Adding the square brackets does not help.

I have also tried adding ` characters, but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

In the `.Compute` expression, the `CONVERT` function is being called inside the `SUM` aggregate. The `SUM` aggregate function is expecting a simple column name, not an expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a datatable and had this same issue. I was using:

```
dataTableNew.Columns.Add("Tax Rate", GetType(System.Double))
```

As soon as I replaced the space with an underscore it worked:

```
dataTableNew.Columns.Add("Tax_Rate", GetType(System.Double))
```

I don't think it likes spaces.